# Theme editor not showing correct index.php

Tags: themes, dashboard

I've run into a weird issue. Not a big deal, but I'm curious about the cause.

I was making a small edit to a site built by someone else; it was also temporary, so I was just using the built-in theme editor. The index.php that is loaded in the theme editor is *not* the version that currently exists in the theme folder; it seems to be a cached, previous version.

This wouldn't be so unusual except that it is only affecting index.php. For every other theme file, changes showed up if I made them on my desktop and FTP'd the file up; likewise, changes made in the theme editor appeared in the actual files.

I have tried:

- switching themes to and from the correct one
- resetting my permalinks in case it was an .htaccess issue
- deactivating and reactivating all plugins (there are no caching plugins installed)

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a child theme is in use? I usually find that the problem is with me looking in the wrong directory, not the system. Not saying that's what you're doing, but that usually what happens to me.